# How to change Windows 8.1 Group Policy programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, group-policy, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am developing a Windows 8.1 kiosk-type application,and I need to set the group policy custom user interface setting to the .exe of the application.  This, of course, can be accomplished by hand, but I would like to be able to change it via c#, or alternatively, an installer (I'm using Visual Studio Setup right now).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Google "gpedit automation", take the first hit.

Comment: Automating Group Policy with PowerShell?  I'll take a look.  Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is:

1. Create a **Custom Action** and add it to the **Install** section of your installer.
2. Use the unmanaged **LsaAddAccountRights** method to set any policy to any user account or group (*e.g. Administrators, Users, Everyone*). All you need to know is the right *Policy Handle* and the *User Right* that you want to assign.

Now, down to the implementation :-)

Please check the code below. This is the implementation I ended up with by analyzing and borrowing different code snippets from different resources:

```
public class LSAManager
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", PreserveSig = true)]
    private static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(ref LSA_UNICODE_STRING SystemName, ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, Int32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr PolicyHandle);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    private static extern uint LsaAddAccountRights(IntPtr PolicyHandle, IntPtr pSID, LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights, int CountOfRights);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern void FreeSid(IntPtr pSid);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    private static extern bool LookupAccountName(string lpSystemName, string lpAccountName, IntPtr psid, ref int cbsid, StringBuilder domainName, ref int cbdomainLength, ref int use);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsValidSid(IntPtr pSid);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern int LsaClose(IntPtr ObjectHandle);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern int LsaNtStatusToWinError(int status);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetLastError();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    {
        public UInt16 Length;
        public UInt16 MaximumLength;
        public IntPtr Buffer;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int Length;
        public IntPtr RootDirectory;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
        public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
        public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
    }

    private enum LSA_AccessPolicy : long
    {
        POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION = 0x00000001L,
        POLICY_VIEW_AUDIT_INFORMATION = 0x00000002L,
        POLICY_GET_PRIVATE_INFORMATION = 0x00000004L,
        POLICY_TRUST_ADMIN = 0x00000008L,
        POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT = 0x00000010L,
        POLICY_CREATE_SECRET = 0x00000020L,
        POLICY_CREATE_PRIVILEGE = 0x00000040L,
        POLICY_SET_DEFAULT_QUOTA_LIMITS = 0x00000080L,
        POLICY_SET_AUDIT_REQUIREMENTS = 0x00000100L,
        POLICY_AUDIT_LOG_ADMIN = 0x00000200L,
        POLICY_SERVER_ADMIN = 0x00000400L,
        POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES = 0x00000800L,
        POLICY_NOTIFICATION = 0x00001000L
    }

    /// <summary>Adds a privilege to an account</summary>
    /// <param name="accountName">Name of an account - "domain\account" or only "account"</param>
    /// <param name="privilegeName">Name of the privilege</param>
    /// <returns>The windows error code returned by LsaAddAccountRights (0 = success)</returns>
    public static long SetRight(String accountName, String privilegeName)
    {
        long winErrorCode = 0; //contains the last error

        //pointer an size for the SID
        IntPtr sid = IntPtr.Zero;
        int sidSize = 0;
        //StringBuilder and size for the domain name
        StringBuilder domainName = new StringBuilder();
        int nameSize = 0;
        //account-type variable for lookup
        int accountType = 0;

        //get required buffer size
        LookupAccountName(String.Empty, accountName, sid, ref sidSize, domainName, ref nameSize, ref accountType);

        //allocate buffers
        domainName = new StringBuilder(nameSize);
        sid = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sidSize);

        //lookup the SID for the account
        bool result = LookupAccountName(String.Empty, accountName, sid, ref sidSize, domainName, ref nameSize, ref accountType);

        // check SID if required: IsValidSid(sid));

        if (!result)
        {
            winErrorCode = GetLastError();
        }
        else
        {
            //initialize an empty unicode-string
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING systemName = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
            //combine all policies
            int access = (int)(
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_AUDIT_LOG_ADMIN |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_PRIVILEGE |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_SECRET |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_GET_PRIVATE_INFORMATION |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_NOTIFICATION |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_SERVER_ADMIN |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_SET_AUDIT_REQUIREMENTS |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_SET_DEFAULT_QUOTA_LIMITS |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_TRUST_ADMIN |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_VIEW_AUDIT_INFORMATION |
                LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION
                );
            //initialize a pointer for the policy handle
            IntPtr policyHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            //these attributes are not used, but LsaOpenPolicy wants them to exists
            LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes = new LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES();
            ObjectAttributes.Length = 0;
            ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory = IntPtr.Zero;
            ObjectAttributes.Attributes = 0;
            ObjectAttributes.SecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            ObjectAttributes.SecurityQualityOfService = IntPtr.Zero;

            //get a policy handle
            uint resultPolicy = LsaOpenPolicy(ref systemName, ref ObjectAttributes, access, out policyHandle);
            winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)resultPolicy);

            if (winErrorCode == 0)
            {
                //Now that we have the SID and the policy,
                //we can add rights to the account.

                //initialize an unicode-string for the privilege name
                LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] userRights = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
                userRights[0] = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
                userRights[0].Buffer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(privilegeName);
                userRights[0].Length = (UInt16)(privilegeName.Length * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);
                userRights[0].MaximumLength = (UInt16)((privilegeName.Length + 1) * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);

                //add the right to the account
                uint res = LsaAddAccountRights(policyHandle, sid, userRights, 1);

                winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)res);

                LsaClose(policyHandle);
            }
            FreeSid(sid);
        }

        return winErrorCode;
    }
}
```

I've put this code in a separate class called **LSAManager** for convenience. In order to use this code, simply call:

```
string userName = "alex";
// Set "Logon As a Service" privilege (for example):
if (LSAManager.SetRight(userName, "SeServiceLogonRight") != 0)
{
    // handle error here
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, to get the complete list of the **Authorization Constants** (like _SeServiceLogonRight_) check the following [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).